# Is there a way to import a Stack Exchange post into Goodnotes or notability on iOS without the cookies notice blocking out the post?

Tags: bug, cookie-consent-dialog

I’d like to import a Stack Exchange post into [Goodnotes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLQOSY199gM) or notability on my iPad via [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29).

However, when I try to do this, the imported note includes a cookies notice which blocks out a large section of the post, even though I do not see the cookies notice in Safari (I think I accepted cookies long ago). I don’t know whether to blame Stack Exchange or the note-taking apps or Safari. Is there any workaround? I suppose I could take a screenshot and then move that into the note-taking apps, but moving files around iOS is such a pain that it would be nice avoid that.

Here’s the Stack Exchange post in Safari, without any cookies notice. I have the dropdown open which I’m using to import into the note-taking apps:

[image: Safari]

Here’s what it looks like when I import to Goodnotes:

[image: Goodnotes]

And here it is in notability:

[image: Notability]

In both apps, the cookies notice blocks a large chunk of the post. This seems to happen consistently.

Comment: Also happening with chrome

Comment: I've never used the apps before, but if they're not taking pictures/screenshots of the site, and instead displaying them in HTML/JS natively OR converting them to PDF, there's some HTML rendering engine which is "loading" the saved page the same way Safari or Chrome loads the page. However, this separate engine does not have a stored session so as far as the page code is concerned it needs to prompt you for your cookies decision.

Comment: @Robotnik That seems like extremely poor design, especially if someone is importing a page that isn't accessible without logging in to a site.

Comment: @Sonic - as I said, I'm not sure of the particulars of how exactly these apps are choosing to display the site, and I can't think of another reason why the cookie popup would be showing.

Comment: Any idea if this is also a common issue with other sites that use similar popups, or is something unique to Stack?